# Using Ajax in a PHP class

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a simple website using php in a mvc fomat and I'm trying to use ajax to call a simple clock but having trouble. Right now im just tyring to get a "hello world" example in my code to get started and go from there. An example format of my php class is : (the hello.php just echos hello world, and a Run() is being called at an index.php). For the life of me I can not get the script to work , any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

```
<?php
class MyFile{
   public static function Run(){
       MyFile::show();
   }
   public static function show(){
        echo 'html stuff';
    ?>
    //run this sample ajax script i found //
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
       $.get("hello.php", function(data){
           alert(data);
       });
     });
     </script>
    </body>

    <?php 
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You have `error_reporting` on? I'm fairly sure that you can't break up a class definition like that so I would have thought you would get errors..

Comment: Any errors? Either visible on screen or in the logs? Or in the Javascript console? Can you verify if the code is executed in the first place? If you reach the part where the call is made, can you verify if a request is actually made? Do you see anything if you add error reporting to the PHP script? This stuff should be easy for you to find in the developer tools in the browser and in your server log, and it would narrow down the question tremendously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we disregard the fact that your provided example code is a mess of PHP + HTML.

The provided code works just fine if you know how to call it via php, e.g.:

```
$obj = new MyFile(); // instantiate obj/class
$obj::Run();         // execute static method
```

Advice in general: try to avoid writing mixed "view (html)" + "logic (php)" code especially like the example you provided where it's a class no less.

If you can't help it at least you can make it look cleaner by using ***include*** or similar in php.

Here is a bit of longer explanation why you should try to avoid mixing:

- [Should I Include PHP code in HTML or HTML in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291819/should-i-include-php-code-in-html-or-html-in-php)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I figured it was kind off a mixed logic kind of thing, but i wanted to try it anyways. I will go about it in a different way, or most likely not add it all since it is not important. Thank you for the help and replies.

Comment: @adrianm I'm glad it helps.